# Adding Storyboard UIViews to an Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

I've Google'd myself blind and haven't been able to locate what I'm looking for. I'm new to XCode and Objective-C, but am progressing quite quickly ... however ...

If I'm using Storyboards on a singleView application, and I manually add UIViews to that Storyboard (say, representing images that I'm going to drag-n-drop), how do I get those UIViews into an Array so that I can loop through them programmatically? Now, I've been able to create the subViews through code and then add them to an Array just fine, but if I create the subViews within the Storyboard first (which simplifies designing the overall layout) and I then try to add those Storyboard UIViews to an Array, that Array comes up empty with X & Y positions of 0.

My first assumption is that the instances of the UIViews created in the Storyboard aren't instantiated at the time ViewDidLoad gets executed (where I'm trying to populate the Array), but I'm uncertain. My goal is to be able to place those UIViews in their respective locations visually from the Storyboard layout, and then add those UIViews to an Array during application launch, saving their starting locations on screen, etc.

//

Ok, thanks to Andrew's reference to IBOutletCollections, I've finally got my UIViews storing in an Array on App launch, however their represented frame locations are NSLog'ing out to {0,0} in the console even though their elsewhere on the Storyboard. I've got an Init method being called from ViewDidLoad that looks like the following:

```
- (void)initialize {

    dragViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: dragView1, dragView2, dragView3, nil];
    dragTargets = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: dragTarget1, dragTarget2, dragTarget3, nil];

    NSLog(@"arrayImages contains %d items. Contents = %@",[dragViews count], dragViews);
    NSLog(@"arrayTarget contains %d items. Contents = %@",[dragTargets count], dragTargets);

    int i;
    int count = [dragViews count];
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        UIView *currentView = [dragViews objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog (@"My view's center is: %@\n", NSStringFromCGRect(currentView.frame));
    }
}
```

But my console is not representing their current locations properly:

```
2013-02-15 10:43:09.538 dragAssign[4869:11303] arrayImages contains 3 items. Contents = (
    "<UIImageView: 0x92066b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9206710>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x9006510; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9006570>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x90065a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9006600>>"
)
2013-02-15 10:43:09.545 dragAssign[4869:11303] arrayTarget contains 3 items. Contents = (
    "<UIView: 0x92062a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9206350>>",
    "<UIView: 0x92055d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x92053a0>>",
    "<UIView: 0x9206650; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x92057d0>>"
)
2013-02-15 10:43:09.546 dragAssign[4869:11303] My view's center is: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-02-15 10:43:09.546 dragAssign[4869:11303] My view's center is: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-02-15 10:43:09.547 dragAssign[4869:11303] My view's center is: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Suggestions? How would I interate through that array and get the correct frame locations? Big thanks again to Andrew for the pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [IBOutletCollection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html). There's a short post explaining it here: http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/

As for saving the views' starting location, you'll need to do that yourself by iterating over the views in the outlet collection array probably in `-viewDidLoad`, and storing each view's frame somewhere.

Comment: Andrew, awesome suggestion! Thank you for that. I never knew about IBOutletCollections.